# "alter routine command denied to user" error when installing extensions?

Tags: extension, installation, mysql

I have installed civicrm 4.7 on drupal 7. Installing of extension failed with error:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS civicrm_strip_non_numeric [nativecode=1370 ** alter routine command denied to user 'civicrm'@'localhost' for routine 'civicrm.civicrm_strip_non_numeric']
```

I have grant all to the database, named civicrm.

Comment: Which extension are you installing, and how did you try to install it -- from the Manage Extensions screen or manually by putting the files in your extension directory?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have already tried the "GRANT ALL" command before. It did not fix the error. Also, i have tried the civicrm_dbtools, but it isn't support the version ("FATAL: Don't recognize version 4.7.12").

Comment: Okay, I gave the persmissions with "GRANT ALL" again and it works.
Thank you very much :-)

Comment: I installed CiviSepa, which is not from the public extension directory and put it to the extension directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some permissions won't be granted when you use 'GRANT ALL' before the database has been created. Rerunning your GRANT ALL should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The user does not have the permissions to alter and create routines (functions). This should fix it:

```
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON civicrm.* TO civicrm;
```

Comment: This is probably correct, but you should address the question's claim to have already granted all.